# Socat and systemd

Tags: socat, systemd

I need to run a script, which among many things running socat. 
Running the script from the command line works fine, now what I want is that this script is run as a service.

This is the script I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -e

TTY=${AQM_TTY:-/dev/ttyUSB0}

/reg_sesion/create
DESTINOS=(http://127.0.0.1)

LOG_DIR=./logs-aqm

mkdir -p "${LOG_DIR}"

###ADDED####

echo $$ > /var/run/colector.pid

socat -b 115200 ${TTY},echo=0,crnl - |

grep --line-buffered "^rs" |
while read post; do
for destino in ${DESTINOS[@]}; do
wget --post-data="$(echo "${post}" | tr -d "\n")" \
-O /dev/null \
--no-verbose \
--background \
--append-output="${LOG_DIR}/${destino//\/}.log" \
"${destino}/reg_sesion/create"
done

echo "${post}" | tee -a "${LOG_DIR}/aqm.log"
done
```

And the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=colector

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/colector.pid

User=root
Group=root

#ExecStart=/root/socat.sh
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/root/socat.sh'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the service, the process starts and ends quickly.

any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Comment: First of all, change ExecStart line to `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/root/socat.sh'` or use `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/sh` if you like.
As I can understand your service file script is to output data from `/dev/ttyUSB0` to `stdout`, right? And you set a `PIDFile` for it. So, `systemd` looks for the file a while and if there is no such it may think that the service has failed and the process will be forced to finish. You have to put pid of the process to `/var/run/collector.pid` file.

Comment: I've totally forgot about it:
Put this: `echo $$ > /var/run/collector.pid` before running of `socat` to the script.

Comment: I modified the script to your specifications, and added the full script which contains the socat command. 
There were only socat asylum because he knew that it was he who will not work. 
I appreciate your time.

Comment: Is the service active?

Comment: no, now sd crashed (murphy's law), im reinstallig.

Comment: i have a raspberry :D

Comment: I abandoned the idea of ​​using systemd, I was working with archarm. 
After the sd failed, I changed the sd one containing raspbian and use the method of debian services, and works well. 
In the coming days I will try to systemd based on your instructions, thank you very much for your help. 

Just for the time spent not in vain, and can serve others.

Answer (score 3):

Remove *PIDFile=* from your service file, and see whether it works.

*PIDFile=* is mainly for *Type=forking*, where your startup program would fork a sub-process, so you tell SYSTEMD (via PIDFile) to watch for that process.    In case of *Type=simple*  , with your long-running service, SYSTEMD will create a sub-process to start your service, so it knows exactly what the PID is.